# Change of variables in double integrals .

Tags: calculus, integration, change-of-variable

Use an appropriate change of variables to evaluate the double integral
$$
\iint_\Omega  \frac{1}{4}\left (y^2-x^2\right )dA 
$$

where $\Omega$ is the triangle with vertices $(0,0), \; (2,2),$ and $(1,3)$.

I know that the new $(u,v)$ region should be the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$,$(2,0)$ and $(2,1)$ so that $(0,0)$ maps to $(0,0), \; (2,2)$ maps to $(2,0)$ and $(1,3)$ maps to $(2,1)$, but I don't know how to find $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$ and hence find the corresponding transformation.

Comment: How about $u = x+y, v = -x + y$

Comment: Notice, as Doug did, that $y^2-x^2=(y-x)(y+x)$ and that lines map to lines under linear changes of coordinates.

Comment: that was my idea but my tutor said that it is wrong because if I let u=y+x, for example, then 3+1=4 and not 2 as it is required. Do you think 1/2(y+x) and 1/2(y-x) would work fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the variable changes (equivalent to 45-degree rotation),

$$x = \frac 1{\sqrt2} (u-v),\>\>\>\>\>y=\frac 1{\sqrt2}(u+v)$$

The integrand becomes,

$$\frac{1}{4}(y^2-x^2)=\frac12 uv$$

and the three vertexes are instead $(0,0)$, $(2\sqrt2,0)$ and $(2\sqrt2,\sqrt2)$. The corresponding area in the $uv$-plane is confined by $v=0$, $u=2\sqrt2$ and the line $v= \frac12 u$. The area integral becomes,

$$\frac12\int_0^{2\sqrt2}\int_0^{\frac12u}uv\>dvdu=1$$

Comment: Hi I like your method as I thought of a 45 degree rotation as well but I didn't know the transformation corresponding to it. Could you explain how you got the transformation please? That would be great

Comment: @MorenaDragomir - The 45-degree is a special case of the general coordinate rotation which is normally performed via the rotation matrix. See the attached link for the rotation expressions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix